# parallel program in c using openmp is not working correctly

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

when I run this code in code blocks it gives a strange output

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
 {

int id, var2=2, var3 =3;

/* sequential code */
printf("I am a serial region. \n");

#pragma omp parallel private(var2) shared(var3)
{
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    if(id == 0){
        var2 = 22;
    }
    printf ("hello from thread %d\n" , id);
    printf("var2 %d \n " , var2);
    printf("var3 %d \n " , var3);
}

/* sequential code */
printf("I am a serial region. \n");
}
```

so, why the output is not organized ?

[image: output]

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into the question instead. Ad if you get unexpected output, then please also try to show us what output you expected. Also please take some time to refresh ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, unless you have any kind of synchronization between your threads, you don't really have any control over when they would run or in what order.

Comment: _so, why the output is not organized ?_ So, what do _you_ mean by "organized"? I _assume_ you mean that the `printf` output from the threads is _interspersed_. That is, you _don't_ get nice, clean output that is (e.g.) _all_ output for thread 1, _all_ output for thread 2, ... Of course, you won't because the threads run in _parallel_ and thus you have _no_ ordering. To order the result, you'll need an interthread synchronization method of some sort.

Comment: @CraigEsty i mean that printf is not printing the whole line

Comment: Which line isn't fully printed? If you take all the output shown, and puzzle it together, then you should see that it is really all the output you write. It's just messed up. We could have helped you with that, but it's impossible to copy-paste text from an image! Which is one reason you should never show images of text.

Comment: Declare your variables in the minimal scope. That has been feasible since at least C99, so it's time to catch up wit the modern world of twenty years ago. (That will fix at least one bug, and simplify code by  making you remove some of the OpenMP anotations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about the messed up lines rather than things out of order. You can't expect parallel printing in any order. That's just the nature of doing things in parallel.

If you are referring to the line that goes `hello from threadhello from thread 1` and the weird `v 0`, what you are probably dealing with is a [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Any variable outside of a work region, is by default shared. You didn't explicitly declare id as private or shared so it is automatically shared between threads. You may be accessing and writing the value of id at the same time between threads. Anytime you have a data race, the behavior is undefined so you could see all sorts of weird things. To fix, you will need to specify it as private or just declare id in the for loop.